# c++ change array by index inside function

Tags: c++

```
void changeArray(char* str1) {
        str1[0] = 'f';
}

int main() {
        char* msg1 = "andrew";
        changeArray(msg1);
        cout << msg1 << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Hi guys,i dont understand why i'm getting segmentation fault. pointers cannot be accessed by index inside functions? (C++)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to modify [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal), which leads to undefined behavior.

> Attempting to modify a string literal results in undefined behavior: they may be stored in read-only storage (such as .rodata) or combined with other string literals:
>
> ```
> const char* pc = "Hello";
> char* p = const_cast<char*>(pc);
> p[0] = 'M'; // undefined behavior
> ```

And, `char* msg1 = "andrew";` is not allowed since C++11,

> In C, string literals are of type `char[]`, and can be assigned directly to a (non-const) `char*`. C++03 allowed it as well (but deprecated it, as literals are `const` in C++). C++11 no longer allows such assignments without a cast.

You can construct and pass a `char` array instead.

> String literals can be used to initialize character arrays. If an array is initialized like `char str[] = "foo";`, `str` will contain a copy of the string `"foo"`.

E.g.

```
int main() {
    char msg1[] = "andrew";
    changeArray(msg1);
    cout << msg1 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So how can i modify the first letter in that char* ?

Comment: @AlexandruStoica Answer revised.

Answer (score 0):

In `int main()` you declared msg1 as a pointer to a char, not as an array of chars. Do this: `char msg1[] = "andrew";`.